# Rate law of the iodine clock reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I am dealing with the iodine clock reaction, which has the half-reactions:
$$\begin{alignat}{2}\ce{H2O2 (aq) + 2I- (aq) &-> I2 (s) + 2 OH- (aq)} &&\quad (\text{slow}) \\ \ce{I2  (s) + 2S2O3^2- (aq) &-> 2I- (aq) + S4O6^2- (aq)} &&\quad  (\text{fast}) \end{alignat}$$

Now, I have to find the rate law. What I did was 4 solutions – one with standard amounts, another with double the $\ce{I-}$, one with double the $\ce{H2O2}$, and one with double the $\ce{S2O3^2-}$. I recorded the amount of time for the ppt ($\ce{I2}$) to appear. Now I have to calculate the rate law.

The thing is, I am not quite sure how. Usually you take the "slow" step and set up an equation based on that, like $\text{rate}=\ce{[H2O2]$^x$ [I- ]$^y$}$. However, the reaction is not just dependent on those chemicals, it's also dependent on the $\ce{S2O3^2-}$. When it was doubled, the reaction was significantly slower (for obvious reasons).

How do I set up the rate law for this reaction? Or, if I can't, what else can I do with my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, the only reaction that you are studying is the first reaction:  the conversion of $I^-$ to $I_2$ by hydrogen peroxide.  The thiosulphate reaction is simply a dramatic way to indicate when a particular amount of iodine has been produced.

The reaction was **not** slower when you doubled the amount of thiosulphate.  Twice as much iodine needed to be produced (and reconverted to iodide ion) before the thiosulphate was consumed and the first **permanent** iodine changed the starch indicator blue.

Comment: Although, doesn't the fact that $\ce{[I^{-}]}$ stays constant as a result of the fast reaction mean that it has an effect (not necessarily slower) on the reaction rate?